# \\hat not aligned in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

I created a Shiny app, in which I use `\\hat` in combination with `withMathJax` several times.

As you can see from the screenshot, the hats are not aligned correctly above the p and q:

hats not rendering properly

[image]

I am expecting the hat to be above the p and q.

The code of the app can be found [here](https://github.com/AntoineSoetewey/statistics-201) and the app [here](https://antoinesoetewey.shinyapps.io/statistics-201/).

Comment: https://antoinesoetewey.shinyapps.io/statistics-201/ this works fine for me, the hat is on the top of p. Try to "Open in Browser"

Comment: Strange, it works with Safari but not with Google Chrome. Do you also see the issue with Google Chrome?

Comment: Works fine with Google Chrome.

Comment: I tried with another computer, and the issue remains on Google Chrome.